# Selection sort using pointers not working with negative numbers

Tags: c++, selection-sort

I have the following code:

```
// selectionSortUsingPointers:  Using pointers, this function sorts
// in ascending order the n-element integer array using a selection sort.
void selectionSortUsingPointers(int *array, int n){

    int *currentSmall = array;
    int temp;

    for(int *i = array; i < array+n; i++){
        for(int *a = i; a < array+n; a++){
            if(*a < *currentSmall){
                currentSmall = a;
            }
        }

        if(*i > *currentSmall){
            temp = *i;
            *i = *currentSmall;
            *currentSmall = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

It works well with: `array{2305, 1361, 1362, 1331, 1341, 1351}`. However if I try it with negative numbers: `array{-2305, -1361, -1362, -1331, -1341, -1351}` it doesn't seem to sort correctly, giving me this back instead: `array{-1361, -2305, -1331, -1362, -1351, -1341}`. Which is obviously not sorted correctly, and I have been scratching my head trying to figure out as to why. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: What does `currentSmall` point after going thru the `i` loop once?  What should it point to at the start of the second iteration?

Comment: Hint: `int *currentSmall = array;` should be `int *currentSmall = i;`, and as such obviously needs to be moved from its current location.

Comment: Ah sweet what @WhozCraig said works! If you write that out as an answer I'll accept it for you.